# Can iOS 6 app with development target 5 run on iPhone 3GS?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6

I have an iPhone app build with the iOS 6 SDK and a deployment target of iOS 5. 
Can we run this application on an iPhone 3GS?

Comment: be careful though not to use any functions or classes that were only introduced in iOS6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, so long as your iPhone 3GS is running iOS 5 or iOS 6.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can run but your iPhone 3GS should have iOS5 or latter

Answer (score 0):

yes,there are some features the 3gs doesnt have IIRC but it works fine